# Regex match settings pairs

Tags: regex, google-apps-script

I have the following email body stored in a variable in Google Apps Script:

```
var body = messages[j].getPlainBody()
```

body =

```
HOSTNAME=hummingbird
UPTIME=90 days, 23 hours, 12 minutes
LASTREBOOT=12/14/2016 20:45:17
C-USED=638056792064
C-FREE=361226694656
D-USED=
D-FREE=
```

And I'd like to create an array holding this information, e.g.

```
var server = {hostname: "hummingbird", uptime: "90 days, 23 hours, 12 minutes ...}
```

in order to then write the values into cells in a spreadsheet.

Using regex or another suitable method, what's the best way to do this?

Comment: I don't believe there's whitespace at the end of each line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there is newline character (char(10)) at the end of each line you can use split function to create your array like so:

```
function createArray(value){
 //value = EmailBody
 var array = value.split("\n")
 var newArray = []
 for (i in array)
   newArray = newArray.concat(array[i].split("="))

   var newObj = {}
   for (var i =0 ; i< newArray.length ; i++)
    if ( i%2 == 0){
      Logger.log(newArray[i+1])
      newObj[newArray[i]] = "\"" + newArray[i+1] + "\""
    }

 Logger.log(newObj)
 Logger.log(newArray)
}
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks, I'm getting this response when running my function: TypeError: Cannot find function split in object function (search) {...}. (line 62, file "Code")

Comment: newArray = newArray.concat(array[i].split("="))

Comment: Could you log the value of array =>Logger.log(array). Tell me what it logs?

Comment: [17-03-16 00:04:42:747 GMT] [HOSTNAME=hummingbird, UPTIME=15 days, 3 hours, 3 minutes, LASTREBOOT=02/28/2017 20:58:46, C-USED=46834638848, C-FREE=2100094308352, D-USED=1250235031552, D-FREE=897112297472, 
, 
, ]

Strange, because Logger.log(newArray) shows correct data I think

Comment: Copied the above output and tried it at my end, worked fine no problem. try modifying the code like so:  newArray = newArray.concat(array[i].toString().split("=")). And can you also log array[i] in the loop, for some reason one of the array element is typecast to a object?

Comment: Thanks, that doesn't error any more. I don't really understand, but thanks anyway!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138164/discussion-between-jagannathan-alagurajan-and-hazymat).